# JFreeChart ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG is not working in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jfreechart

ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG is working well in the class file, but cannot get the png files after running the servlet file. I got jcommon jfreechart mysql-connector-java servlet four jar files in the lib. And have configured servlet in web.xml. Then what should I do to fix the problem? Thanks

```
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    Connection connect = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXX","root","123");
    statement = connect.createStatement( );
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select acres, tax from XXXX" );

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    while( resultSet.next( ) ) 
      {
          dataset.addValue(
                resultSet.getInt("tax"), 
                "Tax", 
                String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("acres"))
            );
      }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
               "Tax Revenue",
               "",
               "Dollars",
               dataset, 
               PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
              true, true, false);

    RenderedImage chartImage = chart.createBufferedImage(700, 500);
    ImageIO.write(chartImage, "png", os);

    int width = 1500; /* Width of the image */
    int height = 500; /* Height of the image */ 

    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("chart.png"), chart, width, height);
            try{
        if(statement!=null)
            statement.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){}
        try{
            if(connect!=null)
                connect.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

Comment: Use `ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10713897/230513).

Comment: thanks for your help. For my situation, I need to display the charts on pages and also save them to server. The question is I cannot save them to server.

Comment: Verify that it's not a permission problem, e.g. using `File.createTempFile()`, and edit your question with  the results; if your save code works, show the code that fails and the error you get.